# get text between <a class>MYTEXT</a> inside a div class

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i have this source code:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
<a class="btn btn-md white badge-success mt-5" 
href="https://stockinvest.us/trade/WRN" id="trade500signalsTop">
WRN is a Buy Candidate
</a>
```

i want to print "WRN is a Buy Candidate"

i tried the following but it does do not work:

```
page2 = requests.get('https://stockinvest.us/technical-analysis/WRN')
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(page2.text, 'html.parser')
for link in soup2.find_all('a', id='trade500signalsTop'):
link_text = link.text
print link_text
```

Comment: what result does your attempt have?

Comment: nothing at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `header` while requesting the page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'User-Agent':
       'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}

page2 = requests.get('https://stockinvest.us/technical-analysis/WRN',headers=headers)
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(page2.text, 'html.parser')
for link in soup2.find_all('a', id='trade500signalsTop'):
 link_text = link.text
 print(link_text)
```

Output:

```
WRN is a Buy Candidate
```

Instead of `find_all()` you can use `find()` to fetch only one particular value.

```
print(soup2.find('a', id='trade500signalsTop').text)
```